# Error while running Flutter Web Project lib/generated_plugin_registrant.dart:16:3: Error: Getter not found: 'AnotherFlushbarPlugin'

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I yesterday upgraded to Flutter 2.0.6 and when I added web support to an existing project I am getting this error

```
lib/generated_plugin_registrant.dart:16:3: Error: Getter not found: 'AnotherFlushbarPlugin'.
```

AnotherFlushbarPlugin.registerWith(registrar);

[image]

I am using a dependency Flushbar thought it might be due to that I removed that package run flutter clean but no use the error is still there

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue there was package Flushbar code in the yaml file, I removed the line "another_flushbar": ^1.10.10 to fix the issue

[image]